# Parse urlencoded Message with IronRouter in Meteor

Tags: meteor, email

I am using http://mailin.io/doc to parse e-mails to my (future) Meteor application. Therefore I created a webhook using Iron-Router that should process the message and the attachments.

Using the following code, a `{ }` is written in the console.

```
  Router.route('/receive/', {where: 'server'})
  .post(function(req, res) {

   console.log(this.request.body);
});
```

I found some people reporting similar issues but the provided solutions don't work for me.

- https://github.com/iron-meteor/iron-router/issues/909
- https://github.com/iron-meteor/iron-router/issues/1003

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

In the links the correct workaround was described, seems as is I had another error as well. The following code did the trick for me:

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {
    var Busboy = Meteor.npmRequire("busboy"),
        fs = Npm.require("fs"),
        os = Npm.require("os"),
        path = Npm.require("path");

    Router.onBeforeAction(function (req, res, next) {
        var filenames = []; // Store filenames and then pass them to request.
        _.extend(req, {postData: {}});

        if (req.method === "POST") {
            var busboy = new Busboy({ headers: req.headers });
            busboy.on("file", function (fieldname, file, filename, encoding, mimetype) {
                var saveTo = path.join(os.tmpDir(), filename);
                file.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(saveTo));
                filenames.push(saveTo);
            });
            busboy.on("field", function(fieldname, value) {
                req.postData[fieldname] = value;
            });
            busboy.on("finish", function () {
                // Pass filenames to request
                req.filenames = filenames;
                next();
            });
            // Pass request to busboy
            req.pipe(busboy);
        } else {
            this.next();
        }
    });
}
```

and the required route looks like this:

```
 Router.route('/receive/', {where: 'server'})
  .post(function() {

  // Use this.request.postData to access the message content
  postData = this.request.postData;
});
```